# Integral of a square root quadratic with negative leading coefficient

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have this homework problems:

$$\int \dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{-x^2 + 3x - 4}}$$

What i did was take out $\sqrt{-1}$ from denominator, and complete square.
The result I get was :

$$\dfrac{\ln\left|x+ \sqrt{x^2 - 3x + 4} -\frac{3}{2} \right|}{\sqrt{-1}}+C$$

But wolfram alfa gave me the following result:

$$\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{3-2x}{2\sqrt{-x^2 + 3x -4}}\right)+C$$

which doesn't involve $\sqrt{-1}$. I want to know how to proceed for integratin in such types of question.

Comment: The two should be equivalent, but I advise you to stay away from complex numbers.

Comment: @Kenny Yes i differentiate and confirmed that they are equal, but how to stay away from complex number.

Comment: I take back my advice, because the function is (not real) everywhere...

Comment: @Kenny Which function.

Comment: $\dfrac1{\sqrt{-x^2+3x-4}}$

Comment: The problem is that the assignment also gives the answer which wolfram alfa give. Then it become hard for me to convert to other form. i wanted to know method so that answer comes to be the second one  :)

Comment: I would suggest that you contact the teacher and ask what is going on. In any case, you could let $u=(3-2x)/\sqrt{-x^2+3x-4}$, do the calculations as usual, and see where it goes.

Comment: In general your idea of completing the square inside the square root is a good one. If the question made a little more sense, after completing the square you could make a simple change of variables like $z = x + $ constant  to end up with an integrand like $1/\sqrt{z^2 + a^2}$ (or something similar). These types of integrals are well known and can be looked up in tables for example.

Comment: @okrzysik yes it is better to use result, but our teacher ask "show full working and substitutions which lead to result". :) in this example, both the terms in square root has minus sign, so i take $i$ common to convert into $1/\sqrt{z^2 + a^2}$ form.

Comment: Derive the result of Wolfram Alpha and than integrate again. Use the term as *samjoe* has written.